# Server Prerequisite to host angular 4 application on IIS server

Tags: angular, iis-7

I want to host application on IIS 7. Application is developed using angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need anything, if you are making your builds in a local env then just copy your build files from 'dist' folder to your directory in your IIS env.
if you are using jenkins you can use a robocopy to copy the build files to your IIS ENV.

And if you are using Asure, you can follow this:

https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/deploying-angular-4-cli-apps-to-iis-on-azure

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Internet Information Services.
2. Install the URL Rewrite Module
   (If you are only interested in deploying your application to the Webroot, you can skip this step.)

If you are deploying your app not to webroot so it for example different apps will be available under different paths like `*serverUrl/app1/*` and next app `*serverUrl/app2/*`

Use one of the tutorials below:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/
- http://sundeepkamath.in/posts/hosting-angular-application-in-iis-server/
- https://indepth.dev/posts/1239/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis